# Reverse duplicates

Tags: feature-request, review, duplicate-questions

I've been using the review queue to help hunt down and close duplicate questions, but sometimes I'm seeing the case come up where an old question that happens to have a score of zero is being presented (after auto-detection) as a candidate for closure where the duplicated question is newer and less-well-formatted but happens to have picked up a +1 vote. It's *relatively* rare (perhaps on the order of 1% of auto-detections?), but I've had it happen a few times.

Now, this is a case where I currently just say “Leave Open” but I'd like to make a more clear statement within the UI. Could there be the option to say “you've got the duplication the wrong way round” or something like that? I don't mind it being a less-easy option as this is definitely a minority of detected potential dupes, but having to do it by opening the offending (to-my-mind “real”) duplicate question in another tab and vote-to-close-as-dupe it there is a really awkward and clunky workflow…

Answer (score 2):

Just leave a comment below the question, and hope other reviewers look at those.

The other thing I'd do is go to the other 'lesser' question and vote to close *that* one as a dupe of the review question. If the review question is really the better of the two, give it an upvote too. If the other question is really bad, downvote that one.

In other words, use the normal mechanisms to do your bit, and leave it up to the community for the rest.

If you feel really strongly about a particular question, you can star it to come back to it a little later to see how it fared. If the auto-voters have closed it anyway, you could try and flag it for moderator attention (use the `other` option) and make your case for a reversal of the dupe indicator. Or bring it here and have the more active and engaged part of the community review the issue and perhaps re-open and close the other way around. But reserve that for the obvious cases.

As you say, it is rare that it happens, is it really worth it to put in a lot of effort to extend the review UI for those cases? Is it really that much work to go out of your way to do the right thing in these cases?